# How to embed Text on to a Photo when clicked, in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, geolocation, android-camera, mobile-application

Im trying to create a mobile application which uses the camera and the output must be a photo with the details like Date , Time and location embedded on to the photo. 
So ill be needing the location services to be on during the app usage. 
Can someone help me out how to embed those details on to the photo as soon as the pic is clicked ?

Answer (score 0):

If location is enabled then the [EXIF](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html)  for the photo will contain GPS information, so your only job is to retrieve it and draw it on top of the image.

Comment: Can you help me with the code 1)how to get the EXIF and 2)Draw it on top of the image ? 
I'm not able to dynamically get the data for new Photos .